# How to change MySQL Server time zone?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am administrating a MySQL Server. It is installed on a ubuntu server. Recently I discovered, that the ubuntu server was set on a false timezone. I corrected that through terminal by the command `dpkg-reconfigure tzdate`. Now I want the MySQL Server to adapt this setting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf` or wherever it is, check out the [default-time-zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: I got this from the link you posted: `SET time_zone = SYSTEM;` After this command I restarted the MySQL Server and everything was fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [update mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) tables on server for supporting the timezones names.
Use shell command on server:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p
```

Comment: what the equivalent path for windows? /usr/share/zoneinfo I am using windows 10 wamp on this machine

Answer (score 0):

In order to change timestamp on mysql , you can use the below steps.

Connect to mysql server.
mysql -u root -p
TYPE PASSWORD

SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30';

Restart Mysql server by issuing the below query

service mysqld stop
service mysqld start