# Why is mysql server time wrong?

Tags: mysql

I issue the following command on the server:

```
> date
Mon Mar  9 08:16:02 EDT 2015
```

Then I log into mysql and type the following:

```
SELECT @@SYSTEM_TIME_ZONE, @@TIME_ZONE, NOW();
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| @@SYSTEM_TIME_ZONE | @@TIME_ZONE | NOW()               |
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| EST                | SYSTEM      | 2015-03-09 02:10:00 |
+--------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

How can I set the time to be correct?

EDIT: It is not just the hours that is off it is also minutes too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server date/time was off and mysql was using that as the value. I changed it using the following command:

```
date -s 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM-SS'
```

Example:

```
date -s '2015-04-22 10:12-00'
```

To verify, go into mysql and type:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf` or wherever it is, check out the [default-time-zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019540/3164682)

Comment: It is not in that location on my server, so I'm trying to find it. I will update when it finds something.

Comment: It was located at /etc/my.cnf and the value is: default-time-zone = '+00:00'